# My php code is not executing , exactly means values is not adding into database

Tags: php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$uname=$_POST['uname'];
$pswd=$_POST['pswd'];
$cpswd=$_POST['cpswd'];
$fname=$_POST['fname'];
$lname=$_POST['lname'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$address=$_POST['add'];
$mobile=$_POST['mobile'];
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","registration");
$sql1="select usname, email from registration1 where usname='$uname' or email='$email'";
$query=mysqli_query($con,$sql1) or die(mysqli_error($con));
$rownum=mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($rownum != 0)
{
echo "User With This User Name or Email Address Is Already Available";
}
else
{
$sql2="insert into registration1 (usname,psswd,fsname,lsname,email,address,mobileno) values ('$uname','$pswd','$fname','$lname','$email','$address','$mobile')";
mysqli_query($con,$sql2) or die(mysqli_error($con));
echo "Registration Successful";         
}
}
?>
```

I am redirecting to home.php which is written in form action, the php code in this is not executing. can anybody help me to resolve this

this is my html code i am redirecting to home .php on clicking submit button values entered in textbox is not entering into database on clicking submit button.

```
`<html>
<head>
<title>Registration Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<form  method="post" action="home.php">
<table> 
<tr>
<td>
<p>User Name</p>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="uname"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<p>Password</p>
</td>
<td>
<input type="password" name="pswd" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<p>Confirm Password</p>
</td>
<td>
<input type="password" name="cpswd" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<p>First Name</p>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="fname" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<p>Last Name</p>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="lname" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<p>Email Address</p>
</td>
<td>
<input type="email" name="email" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<p>Address</p>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="add" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<p>Mobile No.</p>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="mobile" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: What exactly is not executing at which point? Is no code parsed at all?

Comment: You're going to need to give us better details about what you mean by "not executing"...  are you getting errors? Is the $_POST['submit'] not set as you expect, therefore preventing this conditional from executing?

Comment: How do you invoke or call the script? Show us the form perhaps?

Comment: Most probably because there is no POST variable.
Post your HTML form here.

Comment: How do you mean it is "not executing"?  Any of it?  Or are things not getting put into the registration table?  What exactly is not working?

Comment: **You are leaving yourself wide open to SQL injection.**  If I register for the site with the username `'; DROP TABLE registration1; --`, then you will delete your entire registration table.  Please learn about using parametrized queries, preferably with the PDO module, to protect your web app.   http://bobby-tables.com/php has examples to get you started.

Comment: You should also sanitize your input, at least by running all things you put in the database through mysql_real_escape_string.

Comment: If possible, please use some kind of library to manipulate the database. I like CodeIgniter myself (but CI may be far too heavy for your usage). Also, if you want to see where the error is, add some echo statements along the source. The error will be between the echo statement that prints and the next that does not.

Comment: No need for a framework here, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

at first want to say please describe the error properly.there can be many reason.

**option 1**:maybe $_POST['submit'] or other values is not initialized properly.then it wont enter the if block ever

**option 2**:$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password"); check if this connection establishment is okay or not.

option 3:i am not sure.but i think while fetching multiple column you need to use an array().

please debug the code..find out after which line the code stop executing.you can do this by using echo 'xxx'; as checkpoint in your code and report us

note:use **mysqli_real_escape_string()** and various php mysqli function to be safe from mysqli injection

Answer (score 0):

If there is no Output / No Errors .. Please Make Sure $_POST['submit'] Variable is Posted Vai From..

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="submit" value="submit"  />
</form>
```

this is how your form should be done..add that hidden type

**EDIT 1:** if it doesn't work.then put **echo 'step 1,2,3...'** in your home.php.and check after which statement it stops executing.for exemple you can put a **echo** right after if() to check if it is entering in your if block or not